# Error No instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and I've been working on an assignment where I'm tasked with displaying given social media posts with classes and objects. I was doing okay but I keep getting this error that says No instance of constructor "Post::Post" matches argument list. I think I'm missing something simple and I was hoping someone could point out to me.`

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Post.hpp"
#include <string>

int main() {

 
  Post post1("Chicken came before the egg confirmed!", "A new story just released where we finally get the answer of who came first."); //error appears on this line

  
  std::cout << post1.getTitle() << std::endl;
  std::cout << post1.getBody() << std::endl;
  post1.getTimeStamp();

 
  post1.setTitle("Actually the egg came first!");
  post1.setBody("Ok, maybe the decision is not final.");


  std::cout << std::endl;
  post1.displayPost();
```

**Post.hpp**

```
#ifndef POST_HPP
#define POST_HPP
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

class Post {
    private:
   std::string Title;
    std::string Body;
    time_t Time;
    
    public:
    void setTitle(string title); 
    string getTitle(); 

    void setBody(string body); 
    string getBody(); 
     
     void setTimeStamp();
    int getTimeStamp();
    
    void displayPost();

}


#endif
```

**Post.cpp**

```
#include "Post.hpp"
#include <string>


class Post {
    private:
    string Title;
    string Body;
    time_t Time;
    
    public:
    void setTitle(string title){
        Title = title;
    } 
    string getTitle(){
        return Title;
    }

    void setBody(string body){
        Body = body;
    } 
    string getBody(){
        return Body;
    } 
    void setTimeStamp(int time){
           Time = time;
    }
    void getTimeStamp(){
         struct tm *timestamp;
          time_t ltime;
           time(&ltime);
            timestamp = localtime(&ltime);
              printf("Today is %s",
             asctime(timestamp));

    }
    void displayPost(){
        cout << Title << Time << " :" << Body <<endl;
    }
      
    

};
```

Comment: `Post` doesn't have any constructor at all, least of all one with two string parameters. Read about constructors in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: You also have two declarations of class `Post`. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You also have conflicting prototypes for `setTimeStamp` and `getTimeStamp`, and I'm pretty sure that `getTimeStamp` should work like your other "getters" and not print the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to code a custom constructor of your class Code. It goes like this:

```
class Post { 
   public: 

   Post(string title, string body) : Title(title), Body(body){} // It creates an instance of the class Post

   // Add member functions and variables below
```

Comment: a default constructor that does nothing should not be user defined but rather `= default`. Anyhow, your constructor and destructor do nothing that the compiler generated cannot do as well. OP would still get the same eerror

Comment: Yes sure I edited the answer to a custom constructor

Comment: and still OP would get the same error, because they are passing two string literals. Moreover you should use the member initializer list rather than assignment in the constructor body

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `constructor` to your code that takes two `string` parameters in your `post.hpp` file, something like:

```
public:
  Post(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2);
```